# Android Linear Layout Button alignment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

[image]

I want to develop a Linear Layout something like that. Button 1 should acquire 50% of layout space but, it should not stretch. I will specify the width of Button 1. Similarly, Button 2 and Button 3 should acquire remaining 50% of the layout and I want to specify padding left for Button 2 from center, padding right for Button 3 from right end of Layout.

How can i do this?

My current code:

```
 <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
     <Button 
       android:layout_height="30dp"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_weight="0.5"
       android:text="Button1"
        />
    <Button 
 android:layout_height="30dp"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="0.75"
android:text="Button2"
    />

    <Button 
 android:layout_height="30dp"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="0.75"
android:text="Button3"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of weighting the buttons , you can create two layouts and weigth them with 1 each so they will fill 50% of the screen each .. and then you can manipulate the button size inside each layout as you want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using a LinearLayout with the 3 Buttons, just add the right weight to the buttons, something like that:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" android:layout_weight="4"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```